# Revealjs video not playing

Tags: html, video, controls

I juste resume a project using Reveal.js. I have added and edited a few section successfully and I wanted to add a simple video so I added this:

```
<section> 
<video poster="img/video_poster.jpg" controls> <source data-src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video> 
</section>
```

I can see the video, the poster and I can see the controls, I am just not able to press the PLAY button on the video. I can press on the other controls like "Mute" and "Full Screen", so I imagine is not a problem of z-index. The section is quite simple as you can see, it doesn't have anything apart from the video. Any idea?

I have also tried to remove all my code and create a test page just with the basic code used to initialise Revealjs and it still doesn't work.

Thanks